# Visual C++ Form Variable Errors

Tags: forms, include, c++-cli

I'm new to Visual C++, have added a form to my project, which has given me a file kamisado_board.h with entirely auto-generated code, which I have included at the bottom of this post for reference. I assume this is fine as it was generated by the program.

I've written a separate file, kamisado_main.cpp, and get the following errors upon compiling:

"Error  1   error C2065: 'KamisadoBoard' : undeclared identifier"
"Error  2   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'form'"
"Error  3   error C2065: 'form' : undeclared identifier"
"Error  4   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'KamisadoBoard'"
"Error  5   error C2065: 'form' : undeclared identifier"
"Error  6   error C2227: left of '->Show' must point to class/struct/union/generic type"

I have included the code for this file here:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "kamisado_board.h"

int 
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
bool running = true;
int input = 0;
KamisadoBoard form = gcnew KamisadoBoard;

return(0);
}
```

I figured that it might be a missing #include from my experience with C (I code C for my job but am new to C++), but it's still complaining even with me including kamisado_board.h. Am I missing a line somewhere? I've included the auto-generated form file kamisado_board.h below for reference though I'm assuming this will be correct! Thanks in advance.

---

```
//kamisado_board.h

#pragma once

namespace Project1 {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for KamisadoBoard
/// </summary>
public ref class KamisadoBoard : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    KamisadoBoard(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~KamisadoBoard()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
protected:
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button3;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button4;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button5;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button6;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button7;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button8;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button9;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button10;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button11;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button12;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button13;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button14;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button15;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button16;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button17;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button18;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button19;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button20;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button21;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button22;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button23;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button24;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button25;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button26;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button27;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button28;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button29;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button30;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button31;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button32;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button33;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button34;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button35;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button36;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button37;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button38;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button39;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button40;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button41;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button42;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button43;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button44;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button45;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button46;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button47;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button48;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button49;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button50;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button51;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button52;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button53;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button54;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button55;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button56;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button57;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button58;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button59;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button60;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button61;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button62;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button63;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button64;

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button7 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button8 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button9 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button10 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button11 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button12 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button13 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button14 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button15 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button16 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button17 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button18 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button19 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button20 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button21 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button22 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button23 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button24 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button25 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button26 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button27 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button28 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button29 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button30 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button31 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button32 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button33 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button34 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button35 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button36 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button37 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button38 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button39 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button40 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button41 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button42 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button43 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button44 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button45 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button46 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button47 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button48 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button49 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button50 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button51 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button52 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button53 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button54 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button55 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button56 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button57 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button58 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button59 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button60 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button61 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button62 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button63 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button64 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Orange;
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(43, 24);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this->button2->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Blue;
        this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(72, 24);
        this->button2->Name = L"button2";
        this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button2->TabIndex = 1;
        this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button3
        // 
        this->button3->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::FromArgb(static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(255)), static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(128)),
            static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(255)));
        this->button3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(129, 24);
        this->button3->Name = L"button3";
        this->button3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button3->TabIndex = 3;
        this->button3->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button4
        // 
        this->button4->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Purple;
        this->button4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(100, 24);
        this->button4->Name = L"button4";
        this->button4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button4->TabIndex = 2;
        this->button4->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button5
        // 
        this->button5->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::FromArgb(static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(128)), static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(64)),
            static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
        this->button5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(244, 24);
        this->button5->Name = L"button5";
        this->button5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button5->TabIndex = 7;
        this->button5->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button6
        // 
        this->button6->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Green;
        this->button6->Location = System::Drawing::Point(215, 24);
        this->button6->Name = L"button6";
        this->button6->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button6->TabIndex = 6;
        this->button6->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button7
        // 
        this->button7->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Red;
        this->button7->Location = System::Drawing::Point(187, 24);
        this->button7->Name = L"button7";
        this->button7->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button7->TabIndex = 5;
        this->button7->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button8
        // 
        this->button8->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Yellow;
        this->button8->Location = System::Drawing::Point(158, 24);
        this->button8->Name = L"button8";
        this->button8->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button8->TabIndex = 4;
        this->button8->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button9
        // 
        this->button9->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Purple;
        this->button9->Location = System::Drawing::Point(244, 53);
        this->button9->Name = L"button9";
        this->button9->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button9->TabIndex = 15;
        this->button9->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button10
        // 
        this->button10->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::FromArgb(static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(128)), static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(64)),
            static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
        this->button10->Location = System::Drawing::Point(215, 53);
        this->button10->Name = L"button10";
        this->button10->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button10->TabIndex = 14;
        this->button10->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        this->button10->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &KamisadoBoard::button10_Click);
        // 
        // button11
        // 
        this->button11->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Yellow;
        this->button11->Location = System::Drawing::Point(187, 53);
        this->button11->Name = L"button11";
        this->button11->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button11->TabIndex = 13;
        this->button11->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button12
        // 
        this->button12->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Blue;
        this->button12->Location = System::Drawing::Point(158, 53);
        this->button12->Name = L"button12";
        this->button12->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button12->TabIndex = 12;
        this->button12->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        this->button12->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &KamisadoBoard::button12_Click);
        // 
        // button13
        // 
        this->button13->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Green;
        this->button13->Location = System::Drawing::Point(129, 53);
        this->button13->Name = L"button13";
        this->button13->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button13->TabIndex = 11;
        this->button13->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        this->button13->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &KamisadoBoard::button13_Click);
        // 
        // button14
        // 
        this->button14->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::FromArgb(static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(255)), static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(128)),
            static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(255)));
        this->button14->Location = System::Drawing::Point(100, 53);
        this->button14->Name = L"button14";
        this->button14->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button14->TabIndex = 10;
        this->button14->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button15
        // 
        this->button15->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Orange;
        this->button15->Location = System::Drawing::Point(72, 53);
        this->button15->Name = L"button15";
        this->button15->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button15->TabIndex = 9;
        this->button15->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button16
        // 
        this->button16->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Red;
        this->button16->Location = System::Drawing::Point(43, 53);
        this->button16->Name = L"button16";
        this->button16->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button16->TabIndex = 8;
        this->button16->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button17
        // 
        this->button17->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Yellow;
        this->button17->Location = System::Drawing::Point(244, 111);
        this->button17->Name = L"button17";
        this->button17->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button17->TabIndex = 31;
        this->button17->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button18
        // 
        this->button18->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Red;
        this->button18->Location = System::Drawing::Point(215, 111);
        this->button18->Name = L"button18";
        this->button18->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button18->TabIndex = 30;
        this->button18->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button19
        // 
        this->button19->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Green;
        this->button19->Location = System::Drawing::Point(187, 111);
        this->button19->Name = L"button19";
        this->button19->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button19->TabIndex = 29;
        this->button19->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button20
        // 
        this->button20->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::FromArgb(static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(128)), static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(64)),
            static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
        this->button20->Location = System::Drawing::Point(158, 111);
        this->button20->Name = L"button20";
        this->button20->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button20->TabIndex = 28;
        this->button20->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button21
        // 
        this->button21->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Orange;
        this->button21->Location = System::Drawing::Point(129, 111);
        this->button21->Name = L"button21";
        this->button21->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button21->TabIndex = 27;
        this->button21->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button22
        // 
        this->button22->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Blue;
        this->button22->Location = System::Drawing::Point(100, 111);
        this->button22->Name = L"button22";
        this->button22->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button22->TabIndex = 26;
        this->button22->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button23
        // 
        this->button23->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Purple;
        this->button23->Location = System::Drawing::Point(72, 111);
        this->button23->Name = L"button23";
        this->button23->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button23->TabIndex = 25;
        this->button23->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button24
        // 
        this->button24->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::FromArgb(static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(255)), static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(128)),
            static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(255)));
        this->button24->Location = System::Drawing::Point(43, 111);
        this->button24->Name = L"button24";
        this->button24->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button24->TabIndex = 24;
        this->button24->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button25
        // 
        this->button25->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Blue;
        this->button25->Location = System::Drawing::Point(244, 82);
        this->button25->Name = L"button25";
        this->button25->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button25->TabIndex = 23;
        this->button25->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button26
        // 
        this->button26->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Yellow;
        this->button26->Location = System::Drawing::Point(215, 82);
        this->button26->Name = L"button26";
        this->button26->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button26->TabIndex = 22;
        this->button26->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button27
        // 
        this->button27->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::FromArgb(static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(128)), static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(64)),
            static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
        this->button27->Location = System::Drawing::Point(187, 82);
        this->button27->Name = L"button27";
        this->button27->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button27->TabIndex = 21;
        this->button27->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button28
        // 
        this->button28->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Purple;
        this->button28->Location = System::Drawing::Point(158, 82);
        this->button28->Name = L"button28";
        this->button28->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button28->TabIndex = 20;
        this->button28->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button29
        // 
        this->button29->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Red;
        this->button29->Location = System::Drawing::Point(129, 82);
        this->button29->Name = L"button29";
        this->button29->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button29->TabIndex = 19;
        this->button29->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button30
        // 
        this->button30->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Orange;
        this->button30->Location = System::Drawing::Point(100, 82);
        this->button30->Name = L"button30";
        this->button30->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button30->TabIndex = 18;
        this->button30->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button31
        // 
        this->button31->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::FromArgb(static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(255)), static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(128)),
            static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(255)));
        this->button31->Location = System::Drawing::Point(72, 82);
        this->button31->Name = L"button31";
        this->button31->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button31->TabIndex = 17;
        this->button31->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button32
        // 
        this->button32->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Green;
        this->button32->Location = System::Drawing::Point(43, 82);
        this->button32->Name = L"button32";
        this->button32->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button32->TabIndex = 16;
        this->button32->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button33
        // 
        this->button33->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Orange;
        this->button33->Location = System::Drawing::Point(244, 225);
        this->button33->Name = L"button33";
        this->button33->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button33->TabIndex = 63;
        this->button33->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button34
        // 
        this->button34->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Blue;
        this->button34->Location = System::Drawing::Point(215, 225);
        this->button34->Name = L"button34";
        this->button34->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button34->TabIndex = 62;
        this->button34->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button35
        // 
        this->button35->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Purple;
        this->button35->Location = System::Drawing::Point(187, 225);
        this->button35->Name = L"button35";
        this->button35->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button35->TabIndex = 61;
        this->button35->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button36
        // 
        this->button36->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::FromArgb(static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(255)), static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(128)),
            static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(255)));
        this->button36->Location = System::Drawing::Point(158, 225);
        this->button36->Name = L"button36";
        this->button36->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button36->TabIndex = 60;
        this->button36->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button37
        // 
        this->button37->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Yellow;
        this->button37->Location = System::Drawing::Point(129, 225);
        this->button37->Name = L"button37";
        this->button37->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button37->TabIndex = 59;
        this->button37->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button38
        // 
        this->button38->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Red;
        this->button38->Location = System::Drawing::Point(100, 225);
        this->button38->Name = L"button38";
        this->button38->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button38->TabIndex = 58;
        this->button38->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // button39
        // 
        this->button39->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Green;
        this->button39->Location = System::Drawing::Point(72, 225);
        this->button39->Name = L"button39";
        this->button39->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 23);
        this->button39->TabIndex = 57;
        this->button39->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
```

<... truncated - 30k character limit ...>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm assuming that the `kamisado_main.h` is your main form, because you have the main routine in the `.c++` file.

I cant't see the whole header file, but I think it looks fine, I hope you created the project with the `CLI` option.

You have to create the `form` variable like this, you*re missing `^`, this should resolve all the errors: `KamisadoBoard ^ form = gcnew KamisadoBoard;`

I'm not sure if you can use this native main routine for `C++/CLI`, if it doesn't work try using this code in your `kamisado_main.cpp`:

```
#include "kamisado_main.h"

using namespace Project1;


[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(cli::array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

    // Create the main window and run it
    Application::Run(gcnew KamisadoBoard ());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - the 'using namespace Project1;' line alone was enough to fix the issue :) much appreciated. Can you explain to me please what adding this line in actually does? I assumed the #include of kamisado_board.h would be enough to allow me to do what I wanted but perhaps not.

Comment: Yes sure I can: Namespaces are basically to protect duplicate classes and functions, so you can, for example, have to different namespaces with the same function in it, and there is no conflict. What this line just says is, that you want to use this namespace's content, so in this case the class `KamisadoBoard`. You could also remove this using line and write instead: `Project1::KamisadoBoard form = gcnew Project1::KamisadoBoard;`. It's exactly the same. And you hopefully know this line `using namespace std;` This does also the same.